# Python rglob pattern for directory search

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I try to get the name of subdirectories with Python3 script on Windows10.
Thus, I wrote code as follows:

```
from pathlib2 import Path
p = "./path/to/target/dir"
[str(item) for item in Path(p).rglob(".")]
# obtained only subdirectories path names including target directory itself.
```

It is good for me to get this result, but I don't know why the pattern of rglob argument returns this reuslt.

Can someone explain this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what "glob" means, or what exactly is confusing about this result? [The python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) explain the difference between `glob` and `rglob`, and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) explains glob patterns in general.

Comment: Yes, I mean the latter of your comment, confused about this result. Though I usually use this method with wildcard, in this case, this pattern, in shortly, without wild and only one dot shows only directory path objects. What does the one-dot pattern (“.”) mean for glob?

Comment: Ah, I think I know what you mean. I'll try to write an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every directory in a posix-style filesystem features two files from the get go: `..`, which refers to the parent directory, and `.`, which refers to the current directory:

```
$ mkdir tmp; cd tmp
tmp$ ls -a
. ..
tmp$ cd .
tmp$  # <-- still in the same directory
```

- with the notable exception of `/..`, which refers to the root itself since the root has not parent.

A `Path` object from python's `pathlib` is, when it is created, just a wrapper around a string that is assumed to point somewhere into the filesystem. It will only refer to something tangible when it is *resolved*:

```
>>> Path('.')
PosixPath('.')  # just a fancy string
>>> Path('.').resolve()
PosixPath('/current/working/dir')  # an actual point in your filesystem
```

---

The bottom line is that

- the paths `/current/working/dir` and `/current/working/dir/.` are, from the filesystem's point of view, completely equivalent, and
- a `pathlib.Path` will also reflect that as soon as it is resolved.

By matching the `glob` call to `.`, you found all links pointing to the current directories below the initial directory. The results from `glob` get resolved on return, so the `.` doesn't appear in there any more.

As a source for this behavior, see [this section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0428/#construction) of PEP428 (which serves as the specification for `pathlib`), where it briefly mentions path equivalence.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.
I know `ls -a` command shows one and two dots, of course other files or directories, but I've never thought that much.
Thank you for your time!